# print stacktrace of runtime errors to the file

Tags: java, junit, runtime-error

I have Junit test where sometimes it fails due to runtime errors [image: Screen of the Failure trace]

I was wondering if there is a way to capture this  srack trace without using try catch block and storing it into a file.

I was using

```
        if(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() != null){

           logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Rune Time Exception");
           report.endTest(logger);
           report.flush();
       }
```

but this does not know if there was a failure or not, it goes into the if statement if there is a something in the stack trace. Is there a way to somehow capture the the "Errors" keyword on a JUnit tab? and then log the stack trace into the log file?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a try/catch block?

Comment: Well I have to many data insertion point and if I would try to catch each and everyone due to possible exceptions, it would take me forever. that is why i just was to get a dump file if runtime error occurs so I can see the same thing what i'm seeing in the console, on report

Comment: Usually, in every test method, we put a `try` in the beginning, a `catch (Exception e)` at the end, where the exception is caught, its stack trace is logged, and then it's re-thrown for junit to work properly. Or is each data insertion point in a separate test method in your case?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @RealSkeptic said, just place a global try/catch right inside the method.

Comment: its one test method but i'm passing data between different classes essentially calling the pages via the methods and feed the data into it. My thinking was I was just put the stacktrace into the tearDown() method since its always being called and log it into the file.

Comment: Once you get to `tearDown`, the exception has already been thrown and the stack has already been wound back. The only place where the information exists is in the exception. Just catch it. What does it matter that the method calls pages and data is fed in other classes? If any of them throws an uncaught exception, it will be caught by your `catch`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic No one should be doing `catch (Exception e)`.  Test methods usually should not have any `catch` at all.  Just add a `throws` clause to the test method;  JUnit will treat any uncaught exception as a test failure, and will report the full stack trace in the report file for the class.

Comment: @VGR you seem to miss the point. Junit does its thing, but if you want to add additional behavior when there is a failure, you can catch the exception **and then rethrow** after you finished your additional behavior. Unless you can show a hook that allows adding that behavior to the JUNIT exception handler. One should not catch `Exception` in a normal program. But unit tests are special circumstances, and rethrowing ensures proper behavior.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Perhaps I am missing the point.  I thought the goal was to get a stack trace in a JUnit report file.

Comment: @VGR not in a report file. In a file, which is not necessarily the JUNIT report file (which I'm not actually sure is created when you run JUNIT in Eclipse as the OP does).

Comment: Now i'm confused,  @VGR you say when i add throws on the test method I can capture this throw and store it write it into a file? the file I'm writing is just html report on the test run. I was thinking if there are runtime errors I would be able to capture those  and just stick them into the report as additional information.

Comment: I would be inclined to favor `throws` over `catch` in each method, then transform the JUnit’s XML report files to HTML, using XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a default exception handler. (Java [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)))

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2006/06/13/java-5-global-exception-handling/) about using it.

> ```
> //ExceptionHandlerExample.java
> package com.air0day.machetejuggling;
>
> public class ExceptionHandlerExample {
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>
>     Handler handler = new Handler();
>     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
>
>     Thread t = new Thread(new SomeThread(), "Some Thread");
>     t.start();
>
>     Thread.sleep(100);
>
>     throw new RuntimeException("Thrown from Main");
>   }
>
> }
>
> class Handler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
>   public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
>     System.out.println("Throwable: " + e.getMessage());
>     System.out.println(t.toString());
>   }
> }
>
> class SomeThread implements Runnable {
>   public void run() {
>     throw new RuntimeException("Thrown From Thread");
>   }
> }
> ```